# Data recovery from android device with broken screen

Tags: adb, linux, fastboot, broken-screen, macos

## Situation Summary - I have an Android device with a broken screen, LCD and touch

I have an android phone (BQ Aquaris E4.5 Ubuntu Edition, which I have flashed with the Android firmware for the E4.5 - this is an Android phone, it is not running Ubuntu anymore). I recently broke this phone - the screen does not work, neither the capacitive touch layer of the screen nor the LCD layer of the screen work. However I believe the rest of the hardware to be otherwise impaired.

USB debugging on this phone is not enabled. As I understand it, if I am to recover data from this phone I must enable the USB debugging. I believe this can be done via adb, or perhaps fastboot?

Note: I can use either a ubuntu linux OS or Mac OS X to attempt to recover data from this phone. Currently I have tried installing the Android Studio Software on these 2 computers/OS's and used adb devices to detect my phone, however the device has failed to be detected.

## What should I do next to attempt to recover data from this device?

To be perfectly honest I am slightly lost here. I considered buying a usb to hdmi cable, but I have no idea if my device supports this hardware, and even if it did, the capacitive touch layer of the screen is still broken, so I would be unable to control my phone via the screen...

Therefore I think the most sensible option is to try and use adb(?) to enable USB debugging, and then use some other software to copy data from my android device to one of my computers.

I think the best course of action is to ask what are the next steps I should try to recover the photos/videos/documents from my phone? I am fairly familiar with ubuntu/linux, but I'm certainly not an expert with Android!

What are the next steps I should take to attempt to recover data from my phone/enable USB debugging?

Comment: Welcome to the Android Enthusiasts! For a starter and first-aid, please take a look at our [broken-screen tag-wiki](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/broken-screen/info).

Comment: Unfortunately none of those questions help me